# How did the recovery of the first crewed Crew Dragon water recover differ from previous recoveries of Crew and Cargo flavors?

Tags: spacex, crewed-spaceflight, dragon-v2, recovery, water-landing

The NASA video [Expedition 63 Inflight with New York Times, Fox News, and USA Today - July 7, 2020](https://youtu.be/cguaS3Y6BFE?t=537) includes an interview with Fox News reporter Bill Hemmer, who asks:

> I am most interested in your return to Earth which may happen in early August, the date to be determined, and you’re doing sort of an old-school space reentry into a New Age world. You will use parachutes to slow your descent, they can be tricky, **a water landing hasn’t happened since 1975**, so Bob Behnken how are you getting ready for this?

Of course Dragon capsules have had water landings for quite some time now. From SpaceXFleet.com's [Dragon Recovery](https://spacexfleet.com/dragon-recovery/):

> Dragon is a free-flying spacecraft designed to deliver both cargo and people to orbiting destinations. It is the only spacecraft currently flying that is capable of returning significant amounts of cargo to Earth. The Dragon vehicle has two variants, cargo, and crew. Both capsules return to Earth and splashdown in the Atlantic ocean. SpaceX uses a fleet of ships to recover and return the capsules to land for re-use.
>
> Dragon 1 flew from 2010 to 2020, resupplying the International Space Station under a contract with NASA. The crew variant of Dragon 2 first flew during its demonstration mission in March 2019. A cargo variant of Dragon 2 will fly for the first time in October 2020. Dragon is recovered by ships [GO Searcher](https://www.spacexfleet.com/go-searcher) and [GO Navigator](https://www.spacexfleet.com/go-navigator).

**Question:** How did the recovery of the first *crewed* Crew Dragon water recover differ from previous recoveries of Dragon capsules, *both Crew and Cargo flavors?* Was the logistics be different, i.e. be faster and/or have more ships involved, have more US military and/or Coast Guard participation etc.?

---

From SpaceX [Tweet](https://twitter.com/SpaceX/status/1104032250495004673) Crew Dragon is on SpaceX’s recovery vessel—completing the spacecraft’s first test mission!:

[image: Crew Dragon is on SpaceX’s recovery vessel—completing the spacecraft’s first test mission!]

Comment: Apollo recovery fleet were 12 ships for Apollo 7 and only one for the last Apollo.Soyuz. See a NASA [page](https://history.nasa.gov/ships.html).

Comment: @Uwe: see also https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36188/26446

Comment: Also Cargo Dragon lands in the Pacific (Except one or two tests for Crew Dragon) and Crew Dragon is due to land in the Atlantic, I believe.